# Optaplanner: Access indictment map in custom phase

Tags: optaplanner

I am trying to implement a custom phase in order to clean up the solution provided by the CH phase. This is an overconstrained TWVRP problem with a lot of extra constraints on top, so I understand why the CH is strugglig. My custom phase will just take all stops breaking a hard constraint and assign them to the dummy vehicle, thereby getting me up to a hard score of 0.

However, the scoreDirector passed to the custom phase command does not allow me to access scoreDirector.getIndictmentMap()

My phase so far:

```
public class CleanUpPhase implements CustomPhaseCommand<Schedule> {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(CleanUpPhase.class);

    //Clean up the solution from the construction heuristic phase.

    @Override
    public void changeWorkingSolution(ScoreDirector<Schedule> scoreDirector) {
        ConstraintStreamScoreDirector constraintStreamScoreDirector = (ConstraintStreamScoreDirector<Schedule, HardMediumSoftScore>)scoreDirector;
        constraintStreamScoreDirector.getIndictmentMap();
    }
}
```

I tried to trick Optaplanner into giving me access to the indictment map with a cast but no luck:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: When constraintMatchEnabled (false) is disabled in the constructor, this method should not be called.
```

Is there a way to easily locate the entities breaking the hard constraints some other way, or can I instruct the CH phase to assign offending entities to the dummy vehicle through configuration somehow? All I need is a feasible solution when entering the local search phase.

UPDATE:

It seems that if I implement my own phase completely, I get access to a score director which can give me the indictment map. However, I get stuck on

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown PhaseConfig type: (org.acme.CleanUpPhaseConfig).
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.phase.PhaseFactory.create(PhaseFactory.java:52)
```

How can I get the phase factory to recognize my newly created phase?

Comment: FYI ConstraintStreamScoreDirector is not public API and in fact, in the newer versions of OptaPlanner, it is gone. Rely on internal API at your own peril.

Comment: OK. How would you recommend going about building a custom solving step which can access score impacts of individual planning entities?

Comment: In my opinion, you should not be accessing justifications during solving at all.

Comment: How then can I help guide the CH phase to a feasible solution?

Comment: If we're talking about Construction Heuristics, you should really only need to implement fast and efficient constraints without score traps. CH is a deterministic algorithm. If we're talking subsequent local search, it starts with good constraints, but adding custom moves often also helps.

Comment: Finally, look into OptaPlanner Benchmarker for tweaking the solver config to perform best on your particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a `CustomPhase`, there is no need for a new `Config`. The Existing `CustomPhaseConfig` accepts the `CustomPhaseCommand` implementation as a part of its configuration.
Please refer to [this section of the documentation](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latestFinal/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#customSolverPhase).

However, the `CustomPhase` might not be a solution to your problem. You may run into the same issue in Local Search after your `CustomPhase` unless you make sure your constraints take the dummy vehicle into account. There is a [chapter about overconstrained planning](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latestFinal/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#overconstrainedPlanning), that describes two approaches: either making the planning variable `nullable` or using virtual values, as is your dummy vehicle. If you follow the chapter, you can avoid the `CustomPhase`.

Comment: I can't use nullable planning variables when they are chained, so I'm using the dummy/virtual value. How can I inform the construction heuristics phase that it can assign stops to that dummy in order to get aa feasible solution? I would love to not have to do custom phases or custom phase commands

Comment: I would try adding a score level, e.g. from `HardSoft` to `HardMediumSoft`, and a constraint that penalizes every usage of the dummy vehicle by the medium score level. This way you move the hard score penalties caused by an insufficient number of available vehicles to a separate score level, making the solution feasible.

Comment: That's exactly what I am doing. However, the CH phase does not manage to assign stops to the dummy enough to avoid breaking hard constraints

Comment: Also, I have tried increasing the number of dummy vehicles. The only result is that each dummy is assigned fewer stops, but still there are some visits that break hard constraints. I have a custom init phase where I pre-assign the stops that MUST be performed that day, so every uninitialized planning entity in the solution when starting the CH phase can be assigned to a dummy in order to avoid breaking har constraints.

Comment: Let me be more specific about what I had on my mind. I think you can use just a single dummy vehicle that takes all the stops that cannot be assigned to real vehicles. Then, you penalize with a hard score for every unassigned stop (without any distinction if the vehicle is a real one or not), and in another constraint, you penalize with the medium score for every stop assigned to the dummy vehicle (this way, you force OptaPlanner to prefer real vehicles when possible). All the other constraints should penalize with soft score and only apply to real vehicles.

Comment: I am sort of doing it the other way around. It is unacceptable for my use case to have a visit planned to a real vehicle (or actually employee in my case) which breaks hard constraints. So, those constrains apply only to stops planned to real employees and affect the hard score. Then, I award a medium score for every stop assigned to a real employee. Soft score is used for "nice to have" stuff like minimize travel time. This way, Optaplanner should do the same right? The more visits that can be planned, the higher the medium score will be while still maintaining a 0 hard score.